# How to Positioning absolute elements inside a relative?

Tags: css

I want to positioning 2 absolute elements inside a relative one. That could be done setting the height of outer element.
But I can not use (or should not) fixed height since the content is dynamic.

Here at the example 1 on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w5wtkg7z/1/), I use `height:500px` and the red element can wrap the others.

But If I erase  `height:500px` the red line do not wrap inner elements.

What am I missing?

code:

```
Scenario-1 - height:500px.
<form method="post" action="#" >
            <div style='width:100%;height:500px;border: 3px solid red;position:relative;'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div style='width:100px ;border: 3px solid green;position:absolute;top:0;left: 0;'>
                                1-Item<br/>
                                2-Item<br/>
                                3-Item<br/>
                                4-Item<br/>
                                5-Item<br/>

                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div style='width:100px ;border: 3px solid pink;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;'>                                
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer pretium dui sit amet felis. Integer sit amet diam. Phasellus ultrices viverra velit.
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer pretium dui sit amet felis. Integer sit amet diam. Phasellus ultrices viverra velit
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>  
<br/><br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>    <br/><br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>  <br/>       
Scenario-2
<form method="post" action="#" >
            <div style='width:100% ;border: 3px solid red;position:relative;'>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div style='width:100px ;border: 3px solid green;position:absolute;top:0;left: 0;'>
                                1-Item<br/>
                                2-Item<br/>
                                3-Item<br/>
                                4-Item<br/>
                                5-Item<br/>
                                6-Item<br/>
                                7-Item<br/>
                                8-Item<br/>
                                9-Item<br/>
                                6-Item<br/>
                                7-Item<br/>
                                8-Item<br/>
                                9-Item<br/>
                                6-Item<br/>
                                7-Item<br/>
                                8-Item<br/>
                                9-Item<br/>
                                6-Item<br/>
                                7-Item<br/>
                                8-Item<br/>
                                9-Item<br/>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div style='width:100px ;border: 3px solid pink;position:absolute;top:0;right:0;'>                                
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Integer pretium dui sit amet felis. Integer sit amet diam. Phasellus ultrices viverra velit.
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Absolute position of elements within table cells?  That can't be good. Why the tables?

Comment: @JosephMarikle the cell may contain a popout "widget" that expresses a Many to One relationship with the row. Veeeeery common use case, actually. Positioning within the cell allows you to use the cell itself as your widget wrapper, saves the locs from a wrapper element. HOWEVER: this is not the case with this one.

Comment: @zwitterion is there a reason you're putting all content in a single row of the table and using linebreaks, instead of actually using it as a table? I mean, at least it's not using a single table per row, like something I had to rebuild for work... __shudder__

Comment: The title of this question and your first sentence disagree with each other. Which is correct?

Comment: I just used line breaks to create 2 separeted scenarios. Not in the real code.  I am sorry I will corrent the 1st sentence. You are rigth.

Comment: @zwitterion wasn't the `br`s I was referring to. Was talking about the ones inside the table. Was before I realized you were mixing a layout table (which is bad form but not too terrible if you declare your widths and slap `table-layout:fixed` on it) with a positioned laout. The cause of your problem is that absolute positioning __removes the element from document flow__. This means their parent no longer has to scale with them. My suggestion is to either double down on the layout table and do that correctly or use `outline` instead of `border` on the outer element (which respects visual flow)

Comment: Abluejelly, I have a very old web page. The owner dont want spent resources to update tecnology, but he wants the page to be visualized by portable devices. So I am at the first step. I could not have this kind of issue with bootstrap.